# .htaccess replace part of domain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

`http​://sub.A.com/some.html` to `http​://sub.B.com/some.html`

and also

`http​://A.com/some.html` to `http​://B.com/some.html`

---

Basically just redirect **A** to **B**

The .htaccess file is only under **A.com**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]*\.)?A.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://%1B.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Matches with or without the leading "sub." and redirects per the question, keeping the "sub." if it was present. Matches anything in the third level domain.

Comment: I have about 10 sub domain,like `mail``vip``bbs``download`...need `vip.A.com` to `vip.B.com`

Comment: Updated to match anything in the third level domain (vip, mail, etc.).